# Floating point Data generator

Tags: generator, data-generation

Is there a program or source code for data generation?

I want a data generator for Java. (Language does not matter, if I can get the result file)

I want a correlated data, anti-correlated data, independent data.

I want a data generator program that has

input : min, max, data-distribution (ex., independent, anti-correlated, correlated, Gaussian, Poisson ... ), dimension, # of points (n)

output :  n points that follows given data-distribution.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the interval of the generated numbers with some simple math:

```
Random r=new Random();
floatx=(r.nextFloat()%(max+min))-min;
```

The java random class also has an option to return gaussian distributed values.

Comment: Thanks. Does it support anti-correlated or correlated data?